# How to optimize large size mtar for TMS upload?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

We are using mta to structure our application consisting of multiple (11 nos) micro-services (Java + Nodejs + Python).

Using the SAP Cloud SDK Pipeline, we are packaging the aforesaid micro-services into mtar file and then uploading the generated mtar to Transport Management landscape which subsequently deploys the application to SAP CLoud Foundry.

The issue here is with the large size of the mtar generated. The mtar file size in our case ranges between 900 MB to 1.2 GB and that is a pain point as it exceeds the 400 MB limit set in TMS upload.
This fat size of the mtar is mainly because of the packaging of the node_modules (around 350 MB each) in the mtar for the nodejs (2 nos) microservices.

We understand that the mtar size limit to TMS upload can be configured but looking for suggestions on the best practices to optimize the size of the mtar file.
Appreciate if someone can guide us here on the efficient ways to handle the node_modules in the mtar and thereby optimize the large size of the mtar file.

Comment: Hi, I work in the SAP Cloud SDK for Continuous Delivery team and we discussed your question, but I'm afraid that we're not the experts on this subject. Essentially as I understand it your question boils down to "how do I design my mta in a way that it is not as huge". I've forwarded your question internally.

Comment: Update: I think opening an issue here https://github.com/SAP/cloud-mta-build-tool/issues on GitHub is the best place to address your question. There the experts on mta can help you with regards structure of your mta application.